# Can someone tell me what's wrong with my PHP code?

Tags: php, macos, mamp

Using latest version of MAMP. PHP 500 error saying unexpected "." on line 7

```
function get_thumbnail_view_html($thumb) {

$thumb_layout = "";

$thumb_layout = $thumb_layout . '<li class="span3">';
$thumb_layout = $thumb_layout . '<a class="thumbnail" href="' . $thumb["link"] . '">';
$thumb_layout = $thumb_layout . '<img src="' . $thumb["img"] . '" alt="' . $thumb["name"] . '">';
$thumb_layout = $thumb_layout . '<p>' . $thumb["name"] '</p>';
$thumb_layout = $thumb_layout . '<span>' . $thumb["filter"] '</span>';
$thumb_layout = $thumb_layout . "</a>";
$thumb_layout = $thumb_layout . "</li>";

return $thumb_layout;
```

}

Comment: @PRPGFerret - Since when?

Comment: Since it does not benefit the community and frankly.. it literally tells you where the error is?

Comment: FWIW in PHP the code above could also be written as: `$thumb_layout .= '<li class="span3">'; ` etc http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.assignment.php

Comment: @PRPGFerret People new to PHP or programming in general have syntax errors. Maybe they don't understand exactly what's going on yet. It's not a bad question.

Comment: Maybe so, but proper research (heck even basic google search) can solve this. I'm not trying to be mean, I'm just saying 99% of syntax error questions will be downvoted (not just by me, I barely downvote)

Comment: unexpected "."  implies a syntax error, but one wouldn't expect that it means a "." is _missing_. You'll usually have to look at the lines _before_ the line indicated to find the problem.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a basic syntax error.

Answer (score 5):

Looks like you're missing a `.` to concat the string on a few lines:

```
$thumb_layout = $thumb_layout . '<p>' . $thumb["name"] '</p>';
$thumb_layout = $thumb_layout . '<span>' . $thumb["filter"] '</span>';
```

should be

```
$thumb_layout = $thumb_layout . '<p>' . $thumb["name"] . '</p>';
$thumb_layout = $thumb_layout . '<span>' . $thumb["filter"] . '</span>';
```

Comment: Tried this, it is still giving me the same error saying that I have an unexpected "." on line 7. I am fairly new to PHP and have searched my issue online before coming here.

Comment: I figured it out. I actually didn't have any syntax error at all. I was editing the copy of the file and not the original. derp.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add a dot(.) before

and  at line 6 and 7

the code would be as follow:

```
    function get_thumbnail_view_html($thumb) {

$thumb_layout = "";

$thumb_layout = $thumb_layout . '<li class="span3">';
$thumb_layout = $thumb_layout . '<a class="thumbnail" href="' . $thumb["link"] . '">';
$thumb_layout = $thumb_layout . '<img src="' . $thumb["img"] . '" alt="' . $thumb["name"] . '">';
$thumb_layout = $thumb_layout . '<p>' . $thumb["name"] .'</p>';
$thumb_layout = $thumb_layout . '<span>' . $thumb["filter"]. '</span>';
$thumb_layout = $thumb_layout . "</a>";
$thumb_layout = $thumb_layout . "</li>";

return $thumb_layout;
```